# Giving a parser as attribute in getJSON jquery function

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

Function **cue.getCueAsSource();** gives me a nice and clean JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
"A" :
    {
        "B" : [{"value" : "brunos homepage" , "type" : "literal"}]
    }
}
```

I need to place that output in first argument of getJSON function so I can get whatever data I need from that JSON file. Since it will not accept function as a parameter, I'm placing it in a variable for it is a string (I have a hunch that there is something wrong with that).

```
var cueText = cue.getCueAsSource();

$.getJSON(cueText, function(json) {
    $('#meta').html('<p>Title: ' + json.A.B[0].value + '</p>');
});
```

But it throws me this error in firebug:

```
GET { "A" : { "B" : [{"value" : "brunos homepage" , "type" : "literal"}] } }
500 Internal Server Error
```

What is wrong? Is there any other way to place json output from some function into getJSON function? Thanks a lot. Again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `$.getJSON()` for this.  `$.getJSON()` is an alias to `$.ajax()` and is used to retrieve JSON formatted data from the server and pre-parse it into an object before giving it to you.

You already have a string of JSON, apparently, and simply need to parse it.  Use:

```
var cueText = cue.getCueAsSource();
var cueObject = JSON.parse( cueText );
$('#meta').html('<p>Title: ' + cueObject.A.B[0].value + '</p>');
```

All browsers, except for IE, have the standard JSON API built in.  For IE, downalod [Crockford's json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) and include it on your page.  It is smart enough to leave the standard API alone if present, and provide it if not. I prefer to include it just ahead of jQuery so that jQuery is always using the standard API as well.

Comment: Yes, I understand now, it works well!

I have a side question too, is there any way to access values inside this structure if the Subject and Predicate names are changing dynamically?

Maybe some get function that returns "A" and "B" (in this example), or something similar. Also, if there are several nested Predicates in "A" structure.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! For your side question, I'm really not sure what you're asking--partially because I don't understand your terminology, and partially because I have no concept of what your system looks like or what it is doing. Perhaps you should start a new question where you'll be able to better explain it and provide more code and data samples.

Comment: I'm using the rdf/json syntax - [link]http://docs.api.talis.com/platform-api/output-types/rdf-json ,  
so the **A** is actually "subject" and **B** is "predicate", the problem is that they are changing dynamically. So, I need to somehow fetch them from json structure, instead of typing the path to the specific **value** manually.
 
`var a = ''; //how to get the rfd/json subject?
var b = ''; //how to get the rdf/json predicate?
$('#meta').append(cueObject[a][b][0].value);`